# Resize Breaks Page Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've set jQuery's accordion ui widget to fill space and resize on demand. Whenever the resize takes place, the accordion cuts through the page footer, which I've 'fixed' to the bottom of the page. I've also tried setting the footer to: `#footer {position: absolute; bottom: 0; }` but on resize the footer moves nearly to the middle of the page. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions on how I can handle the resize so the newly sized accordion does NOT pass through the footer?

Comment: Would you mind linking us to the page producing the issue, or creating a jsFiddle with your code for the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try make a container and set its CSS to

```
overflow:auto;
```

Or try set the container to:

```
display: table;
```

and the #footer:

```
display: table-row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS in the same `div`. (which is resizable).

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: You should learn how to use the markup (there are formatting buttons to help you). I have added the markup for a code block to your answer (and made a gratuitous change to your turn of phrase to get past the requirement that edits alter 6 non-whitespace characters).